# How can I graph a regression model?

Tags: python, plot, graph, model

I fitted data to a polynomial equation using a mixed linear regression fit (mixedlm):

y = a + bx + cx2

The model gives me a, b and c, and I want to quickly create the graph of the polynomial curve.

Is there a fast way to do it without having to manually enter all of the parameters in the formula?

I read of coefplot2 but I was not able to install it on python, any suggestion would be welcomed thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: There are many plotting packages available -- and asking for recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Generating the values is basic programming, a straightforward loop.  Where are you stuck on that part?

Comment: Can you give some sample desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it is unclear what you want *exactly*. Based on my understanding, in case you want to *always* fit a *2nd degree polynomial*, you can use NumPy's `polyfit` and `poly1d` to get the fit and use it to further plot your graphs. Below is an example where you don't have to enter the coefficients `a`, `b` and `c` manually to create graphs:

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = x**2 + np.random.normal(-2,2,10) # Adding random noise to y = x**2

xmesh = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100) # Fine x-mesh for plotting
fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2)) # 2nd order polynomial fit

plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label = 'Original data') # Plotting original data 
plt.plot(xmesh, fit(xmesh), label = 'Fit') # Plotting polynomial fit  
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```

**Resulting Plot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "manually". A simple thing that would work would be (using numpy and matplotlib)

```
 x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000) #put your real domain here
 y = a + b*x + c*x**2 #you have these values from the model
 plt.plot(x, y)
 plt.show()
```

Comment: I have several datasets to run and I don't want to manually enter the coefficients for everyone of them . I  am wondering if there is a way to automatically create the curve from the model results